# Passing an array of objects into another class constructor (Arduino IDE)

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino

I am trying to pass an array of objects into another array, I am using the Arduino IDE, so I don't think using Vectors is possible.

The code complies, however it does not do what I wanted it to. (To use the the method of the passed object)

```
class Menu_Manager
{
private:
    int _currentPage;
    Main_Menu *main_menus[];


public:
    //Problem
    Menu_Manager(Main_Menu *main[], int numberOfMenus)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x <= numberOfMenus; x++)
        {
            *main_menus[x] = *main[x];
        }

        _currentPage = 0;
    }

    void start()
    {
        main_menus[_currentPage]->start();

        if (_currentPage >= main_menus[0]->getTotalPage())
        {
            _currentPage = 0;
        }
        else if (_currentPage < 0)
        {
            _currentPage = main_menus[0]->getTotalPage();
        }
    }

};
```

Main file:

```
Main_Menu timer(1, lcd);
Main_Menu setting(2, lcd);
Main_Menu *allMM[] = { &timer, &setting };
Menu_Manager manager(&allMM[2], 2);
```

Comment: The expression `&allMM[2]` gives you a pointer to the *third* element of a two-element array. And remember that arrays naturally decays to pointers to their first element. I.e. `&allMM[0]` is equal to `allMM`.

Comment: I managed to fix it by using `allMM` and I also had to declare `Main_Menu *main_menus[];` to `Main_Menu *main_menus[10];`! Thank you!